# Docker: ignore permission when create postgresql container

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I created postgres container by run command in docker:

```
 docker run  --name=pg-docker -p 5433:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=s123 postgres:11.5-alpine
```

In `pg-docker` container /var/lib/postgresql/data has this permissions:

```
/ # ls -la $PGDATA
total 128
drwx------   19 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 postgres postgres      4096 Aug 21 00:46 ..
-rw-------    1 postgres postgres         3 Sep  2 10:44 PG_VERSION
drwx------    5 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 base
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 global
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 pg_commit_ts
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 pg_dynshmem
-rw-------    1 postgres postgres      4535 Sep  2 10:44 pg_hba.conf
-rw-------    1 postgres postgres      1636 Sep  2 10:44 pg_ident.conf
drwx------    4 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 pg_logical
drwx------    4 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 pg_multixact
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 pg_notify
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 pg_replslot
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 pg_serial
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 pg_snapshots
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 pg_stat
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:45 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 pg_subtrans
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 pg_tblspc
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 pg_twophase
drwx------    3 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 pg_wal
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Sep  2 10:44 pg_xact
-rw-------    1 postgres postgres        88 Sep  2 10:44 postgresql.auto.conf
-rw-------    1 postgres postgres     23841 Sep  2 10:44 postgresql.conf
-rw-------    1 postgres postgres        24 Sep  2 10:44 postmaster.opts
-rw-------    1 postgres postgres        94 Sep  2 10:44 postmaster.pid
/ # echo $PGDATA
/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

and it's log says `The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.`

Now when i want to use mount binding when created docker i got:

```
running bootstrap script ... 2019-08-31 13:34:38.428 UTC [47] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
2019-08-31 13:34:38.428 UTC [47] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

So i decided to ignore this permissions to send out `data` directory from container to host. I think i should write commend in `dockerfile`.What is your suggestion ? I have no idea to implemented ignore permission!

Comment: With which command did you start the container when you say "mount binding"? Also, it is unclear for me if you used one postgres container where you want to connect to the database from the host machine, or if you are using two containers in this setup? You just want to run a postgres container with a volume for the data and be able to connect to the database from your host machine, did I get this right?

Comment: I am using windows docker so this is complete run command `docker run  --name=pg-docker -p 5433:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=s123  -v d:/datadir:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:11.5-alpine`  and i connected by pgadmin by `5433`port @ElectRocnic

Comment: Yes, i  just want to run a postgres container with a volume for the data and be able to connect to the database from my host machine but i got permission error `has wrong ownership` so i decided to ignore permission but how?  @ElectRocnic

Comment: Well, I tried your command on my linux computer, made a `test` directory, inside this directory I made a new `db_volume` directory. Both, the `test` directory and the `db_volumes` directory are owned by the current user (not postgres) and inside `test` I ran `docker run --name=pg-docker -p 5433:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=s123 -v db_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:11.5-alpine`. The output of postgres-startup was `fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok`. Maybe it is a Windows-specific issue where I cannot help. pgadmin worked.

Comment: db_volume is in your linux host? Where is the location exactly? i mean for example is in `/home/user/test/db_volumes` ? if true, no need add as you run `docker run --name=pg-docker -p 5433:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=s123 -v /home/user/test/db_volumes:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:11.5-alpine` ?  @ElectRocnic

Comment: yes, you can run it with the full name like `/home/user/test/db_volumes:/var/lib/postgresql/data` instead of `db_volumes:/var/lib/postgresql/data`, and it is on my linux-host.

Comment: dude i create db_volumes in `/home/groot/temp/` and run `~/temp$ docker run --name=pg-docker -p 5433:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=s123 -v db_volumes:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:11.5-alpine` inside `temp` directory and by pgadmins i create a database but nothing is exist inside `db_volumes` directory?I think `db_volumes` is created as a volume inside docker!!!@ElectRocnic

Comment: But `docker run --name=pg-docker -p 5433:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=s123 -v /home/groot/temp/db_volumes:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:11.5-alpine` worked . Thnk @ElectRocnic

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad! Volumes cannot be mounted using relative directories, but they also do not fail, so you are right, my db_volumes is empty as well (but it worked). And glad that it works with the full path!

Comment: Actually, have to correct myself again: What docker does if you provide a volume by `-v db_volume:/path/to/inside/container`, is, that it creates a new named volume with the name `db_volume` and stores the data in a default docker-specific path on your host. You can find that with `docker volume ls`: there you should be able to see `db_volume`. Then you can get the path of the files with `docker volume inspect --format '{{ .Mountpoint }}' db_volume`. In my case it is located in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/db_volume/_data`.

Comment: So, the database files are indeed persisted, also, you don't have to care about their location, docker does the work for you. (Most likely you don't ever bother about the database files, because most likely you will never use the database files directly, rather you will use them via the running database service through your app or pgadmin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked for me on linux with this command, maybe it is a Windows-specific issue?

`docker run --name=pg-docker -p 5433:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=s123 -v /full/path/to/db_volumes/on/host/machine:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:11.5-alpine`